# using the interception driver when the mouse is not connected to the computer

Tags: python, interception

mouse control with interception driver when a mouse is not plugged in

I made a mouse control system with the interception driver, when I ran it with remote control on my second computer, I realized that it doesn't work. After the experiments I did, I realized that if no mouse is plugged into the computer, I cannot control the mouse with the interception driver. How can I solve this?

the library I use: [interception-python](https://pypi.org/project/interception-python/)

my code:

```
import interception

interception.click(100, 100)
```